# how to cut or trim audio song in android programmatically?

Tags: android, audio

I want to cut or trim audio song in android programmatically. i have found FFMPEG solution but i am not getting what is the step behind to cut audio song and if any other way please help me.

most people give me this type answer

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3
```

what is this and how to use in android code to cut audio?

Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: have you tried:
ffmpeg -t 30 -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3

Comment: @Farzan how to use this command.. actually this is my query? what is this? and how to use in android? "ffmpeg -t 30 -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3" i have window os. is it run on linux or is it possible in window os? every time this command in front of me but i want to code of java. how can i programmatically run this command in android in our class?

Comment: @Farzan can you describe full steps ?

Comment: you need to add the ffmpeg libraries to your android project and you need to compile it with NDK. you can use the above command directly in your Java file if you have the right dependencies installed.
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: @Farzan is it run in window os with android studio?

Comment: @Farzan brother still i am not getting how to use this command in android or java code?

Comment: @Farzan Thank you , i got it.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Basically follow the steps described here: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

1.) You have to include the ffmpeg Library into your project!
put this in your build.gradle File:

```
dependencies {compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'}
```

2.) before using the Lib, copy the binary file from assets to the device:

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {...}
```

3.) when this is finished you can start executing commands and listen for the results like this:

```
ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {...}
```

where cmd is the array of arguments:

```
String[] command1 = new String[8];
command1[0]="-t";
command1[0]="30";
...
```

BUT: actually I found that the ffmpeg version for android does not work as expected for cutting or trimming audio files! (I got errors for commands that do work on linux commandline...) Hope you will figure it out.

Comment: :-  your answer is right, if my question is acceptable then please up vote my question..

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple hack:

1. figure out bytes per second or millisecond -- `file.length()/duration`
2. get the start and end position where you want to cut audio.
3. read file as bytes and save the portion between `startPos` and `EndPos` in separate file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21137805)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I will try to come back with the working code soon. This is something from what I experienced trying to complete partially downloaded audio file.

Comment: @M can you explain your answer

Comment: Sounds good can you edit with sample code snippet